# System.AuraHandledException: Script-thrown exception

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps, lightning

I'm trying to return the dml error messages to the lightning component.

According to this [doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/controllers_server_apex_custom_errors.htm/) I can throw an aurahandledexception. But i keep getting this error message.

System.AuraHandledException: Script-thrown exception

Comment: similar to: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/122657/testing-aurahandledexceptions/123051